# default values for IEnumerable collection when length is zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a `IEnumerable` collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Config> getConfig(string CID, string name)
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);
    foreach (var item in raw.ToList().Where(x => x.Name!= null))                       
    {
        var x = raw.Count();    
        yield return new Config
            {
                Name = item.Name.ToString(),                        
                Value = item.Value.ToString(),
            };        
    }        
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if this return a length of zero I am then unable to set the attributes to something else, If I have a response of length 1 the attributes are set from the database, however length zero I want to set a dfault value for `Name` and `Value`.

Comment: thanks for the edits I am not so good with spelling

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LINQ solution - this returns the default if there are no items in the enumerable using `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
public IEnumerable<Config> GetConfig(string CID, string name)
{
    return db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))
        .Select(x => new Config
        {
            Name = x.Name.ToString(),
            Value = x.Value.ToString(),
        })
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new Config
        {
            Name = "DefaultName",
            Value = "DefaultValue"
        });
}
```

Comment: Plus one for introducing me to DefaultIfEmpty.

Comment: Works perfectly as well :S not sure which is the nest solution now

Comment: Both are valid.  I personally prefer the more declarative, functional style I've given than writing imperative style loops and conditionals - but it's up to you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to replace the case

- 0 results

with

- 1 result with a default value.

If that is correct, the easiest way is to fix this in the *calling* function:

```
var result = getConfig(...).ToList();
if (!result.Any())
{
    result = new[] {new Config {Name = "DefaultName", Value = "DefaultValue"}};
}
```

Obviously, you can wrap this in a new function:

```
public IEnumerable<ClubConfig> getConfigOrDefault(string CID, string name)
{
    var result = getConfig(CID, name).ToList();
    if (result.Any())
        return result;
    else
        return new[] {new Config {Name = "DefaultName", Value = "DefaultValue"}};
}
```

Comment: if its zero result I want to set a default name and value

Comment: @Mich: Yes. [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) checks for "zero result".

Answer (score 0):

To check if your query did return any elements use Any-method.

```
public IEnumerable<ClubConfig> getConfig(string CID, string name)
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);
    if (!raw.Any()) return new[] {
            ClubConfig 
            {
                Name = "defaultName", 
                Value = "defaultValue" 
            }};

    foreach (var item in raw.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))                       
    {

        yield return new ClubConfig
        {
            Name = item.Name.ToString(),                        
            Value = item.Value.ToString(),
        };        
    }        
}
```

EDIT: You can also omit the `ToList` from your input.

Comment: perfect - I have had to wrap the 'foreach' in the else, and the !raw.Any had to yield a response but this is perfect now works lovely if you add what iv put in as a edit ill accept your answer :)

Comment: @Mich `what iv put in as a edit` and what do you mean by this?

Comment: I had to wrap the foreach in the else and the .Any I needed to add the yield

Comment: @Mich You won´t need to move the loop to an else-statement, because we are already returning from within the IF-statement. Thus the loop may only be executed when the condition will NOT apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LINQ and can maintain lazy evaluation of the `IEnumerable` result as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ClubConfig> getConfig(string CID, string name) 
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);
    return raw.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))
       .Select(item => new ClubConfig
        {
            Name = item.Name.ToString(),                        
            Value = item.Value.ToString(),
        })
       .DefaultIfEmpty(new ClubConfig { Name = "n", Value="v" });
}
```